codeInput not working in sanity CMS with Next.js?
im trying to use 'code input ' and i installed it and configured it
plugins: [structureTool(), visionTool(), codeInput()],
Defined like this in my schema field :
{  
    name: 'content',  
    type: 'array',  
    title: 'Content',  
    of: [{  
        type: 'block',  
    }, {  
        type: 'code',  
    },  
    ],  
},

and i get insert code option in my sanity studio also,but when i click on it i get this error
help me out here,anyone?

Error : Can not destructure property 'media' of  'theme.sanity' as it is undefined.

